# Latex typesetting, continue writing text not in new line

Tags: math-mode, inline

I have a very simple question that how to write SCR_life within text. Not write in the new line. I tried `\[SCR_{life} \]`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX I don't fully understand. Do you mean that you want to write out an underscore, followed by life? I.e. `SCR\_life`, or even `\verb|\SCR_life|`?

Comment: Or are you after inline math mode, i.e. `$SCR_{life}$`. Perhaps better with `$SCR_{\mathrm{life}}$`.

Comment: yes, I wanted to write SCRlife within text, I tried to many ways but didn't go good. for ex: One risk module is the calculation of the capital requirement for the life underwriting risk (SCR_Life). SCRlife should be life underscored. Can you help me, I'm new in latex.

Comment: By underscored, do you mean that 'life' should be in a subscript? Then see my second comment above.

Comment: thank you very much Torbjørn T, that worked and I can continue now

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Wanna answer? Or do you know a good dupe?

Comment: @Johannes_B  [How can LaTeX insert math formula in text paragraph?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/225897) is a direct dupe, though the accepted answer could do with some editing.  [How to use maths symbols in text mode?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/101918) is an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Without more details I assume you want something like:

```
SCR\_Life
```

inside the text.